# Ubuntu 10.04 displays interrface in Symbol font

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, fonts

My ubuntu 10.04 machine displays menu in Greek, instead of English for applications like: texworks, djview, ipe,virtualbox etc. For many other applications like xterm, matlab, openoffice etc the menu font is English itself. I want all menu fonts to be in English and how to do this? Screen shots are pasted below:

screendump of ipe
[image: screendump of ipe]
screendump of VirtualBox
[image: VirtualBox screendump]
screendump of djview
[image: screendump of djview]

Comment: Could you post a screen shot of said menu?

Comment: have posted screen dumps

Comment: It’s English, just with the symbol font. No idea what caused this, though.

Comment: @kinokijuf yea changed the title of the post to reflect that.